# Get Application's main window

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow, uiapplication

UIApplication has a method `keyWindow`, however if an alert view is showing then this returns the window of the alert view and not the main window of the application.

How can I get the app's main window?

Comment: can you Please more elaborate  what are you trying..?

Comment: take a look this question might Help's you :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871241/is-a-mainwindow-xib-truly-needed-in-ios-application

Answer (score 60):

The `UIApplicationDelegate` usually has a reference to the "main window":

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
```

Furthermore, `UIApplication` has an array of windows `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]`.

See the [UIApplication Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication).

Comment: This is optional for the delegate isn't it? I'm hoping for a more "concrete" way

Comment: [[[UIApplication shareApplication] delegate] window] -- works fine.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not 100% sure this works in every case but this should work:

```
UIWindow *mainWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows[0];
```

The windows are ordered back to front so the main window should always be at index 0.

Comment: You should call `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject]` to avoid an out of bounds exception if there are no windows (not like there would never be any windows, but it's a good habit to avoid those

Comment: @michaellindahl even if 12 people agreed. I can't say it's a good habit 'to check something even if we don't know how it works. Even you wrote: "not like there would never be any windows". The best choice here is to write explicitly: "I'm sure there is a window index 0". It will lead you to a bounds exception. And it's Great! You can't win with a strategy as Michael suggested - it will lead to a mess with these necessary checkings. Who knows later if we need them.

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3.0 version of [rmaddy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841229/2305521):

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first
```

I also should add that since iOS 8.0 `UIAlertController` has replaced `UIAlertView` and being a view controller you may no longer face the issue of new windows being created.

Answer (score 3):

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedInstance];
NSarray *appWindows = [NSArray arrayWithArray:application.windows];
UIWindow *mainWindow = [appWindows objectAtIndex:0];
```

I am not sure but this might help.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I was presenting a `popViewController`

```
self.presentViewController(popViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and then in the `viewDidLoad()` of this popViewController **I was adding a subview**, this causes the error in the console and a display bug. So I have to find another solution to make it work. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3

```
    if let window = NSApplication.shared().windows.first {
        // you can now modify window attributes
    }
```

Comment: He said `UIApplication` not `NSApplication`, it's tagged as iOS

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time this has happened in reverse (people answering Cocoa questions with Cocoa Touch answers), I'd be a wealthy man. :) Cut Ted some slack. :)

Answer (score -2):

Swift 3

```
class func sharedInstance() -> AppDelegate{
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    }
```