# iOS: is it possible to capture an image of the splash screen?

Tags: ios, calayer, splash-screen

I was trying to capture and save an image of the splash screen inside `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` using the following code:

```
UIWindow *w = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(w.bounds.size);
[w.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSString *applicationDocumentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
time_t unixTime = (time_t) [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *storePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%ld.png", applicationDocumentsDir, unixTime];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) writeToFile:storePath atomically:YES];
```

However unfortunately the image is saved as a **transparent image**. It is probably because my *UIWindow* object is not the right one. Can anybody please direct me into succeeding with that?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the below code after setting the Storyboard ID for the **LaucnhScreen.storyboard** file view controller.

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LaunchScreen"
                                                             bundle: nil];

    UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                       instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"Launch"];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(w.bounds.size);
    [controller.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSString *applicationDocumentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    time_t unixTime = (time_t) [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSString *storePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%ld.png", applicationDocumentsDir, unixTime];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) writeToFile:storePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this does not answer my question. My splash screen is based on static images, not on a storyboard. I cannot change it for the project I'm working on

Answer (score 0):

Regarding of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841162/4175906)
The UIApplicationDelegate usually has a reference to the "main window":

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this window has no access to the splash screen