# IOS: xcode 4.2 new project

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

In xcode 4.2 what's the way to create a new simple project? There isn't the choice to start a new based view controller application? Can someone explain me the new ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding, here is the translation: Xcode 4.2 / Xcode 3

- A Page-Based App is what was called a Navigation-Based App
- A Single View App is what was called a View-Based App
- A Tabbed App is obviously what was called a Tab Bar App
- An Empty App is what was called a Window-Based App.

Be careful that the MainWindow.xib is no longer created as you start a new project with the Empty App or Single View app template. For more details, you should take a look at this question:

[Is a MainWindow.xib truly needed in iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871241/is-a-mainwindow-xib-truly-needed-in-ios-application)

Answer (score 0):

This Apple [tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.htm) creates an iOS project which has a single view.  It's created using:

> iOS > Application > Single View Application